# Change duplicate element names xslt xml

Tags: xml, xslt

I have been trying to restructure an XML file and have been able to do most of the changes thus far.  What i need to do is change the name of the elements that have now been duplicated as per below.

Input

```
<products>
<product>
<name>name</name>
<description>this description</description>
<code>111</code>
<thumbnail> </thumbnail>
<image1></image1>
<image2></image2>
<image3></image3>
<prodoptions>
<prodoption code="123" description="that description"/>
<prodoption code="456" description="other description"/>
</prodoptions>
</product>
</products>
```

XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/products">
<xsl:copy>
    <xsl:for-each select="product/prodoptions/prodoption">
        <product>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../../name"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../../code"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../../description"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../../thumbnail"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../../image1"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../../image2"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="../../image3"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="@*">
                <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </xsl:element>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </product>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<products>
    <product>
        <name>name</name>
        <code>111</code>
        <description>this description</description>
        <thumbnail></thumbnail>
        <image1></image1>
        <image2></image2>
        <image3></image3>
        <code>123</code>
        <description>that description</description>
    </product>
    <product>
        <name>name</name>
        <code>111</code>
        <description>this description</description>
        <thumbnail></thumbnail>
        <image1></image1>
        <image2></image2>
        <image3></image3>
        <code>456</code>
        <description>other description</description>
    </product>
</products>
```

the second code and description (the ones i pulled out of attributes of prodoption) need to be renamed. I had previously renamed the attribute before it was turned into an element however i find that when i do that now the attribute gets changed to an element before the renaming is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could simply change this:

```
<xsl:element name="name()}">
```

to say:

```
<xsl:element name="option-{name()}">
```

to get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<products>
  <product>
    <name>name</name>
    <code>111</code>
    <description>this description</description>
    <thumbnail/>
    <image1/>
    <image2/>
    <image3/>
    <option-code>123</option-code>
    <option-description>that description</option-description>
  </product>
  <product>
    <name>name</name>
    <code>111</code>
    <description>this description</description>
    <thumbnail/>
    <image1/>
    <image2/>
    <image3/>
    <option-code>456</option-code>
    <option-description>other description</option-description>
  </product>
</products>
```

There are a number of other possible solutions, depending on the exact result you want to achieve.

Comment: Legendary thanks for answering and not downvoting! Didnt really fancy investing a lot of time to learn XSLT to use it once in this project.

Comment: No problem - this is actually an interesting question. P.S. I have offset the drive-by downvote.